# DNS Domain problem

Tags: domains, dns

Today, I created a free domain on grendelhosting.com.

When I try to enter to file manager the host say:

> Your domain is not pointing to our nameservers at the moment, so services like FTP, file manager, email will not work correctly. You can find our nameservers at the Account -> Details. Please mind that DNS might take up to 24 hours to propagate when the change is submitted.

What should I do? I reset to default the nameservers and now there are the same to account -> details(nameservers). I think i must just wait.

Comment: You will just have to wait. The Internet is a huge thing that just plain takes a while for changes to appear. Your domain does not resolve yet. It generally takes anywhere from 24-72 hours for a domain name to propagate through the entire Internet. Just make sure you are following the directions your host is giving so that you do not have to wait too long before you can get started.

Answer (score 2):

As you already said, you just have to wait. If you are 100% sure you setup your nameservers correctly and your registrar can confirm this, then you'll just have to wait. :-)